# How can i separate(?) url into maindomain + rest?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a php-mysql based page.

I stored a ton of google search result data (id, title, url) in my db and I want to show the list of it on my php page with each website's favicon next to them

```
maindomain.png / '<'a href = url'>'title'<'/a'>'
```

for example

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=php+url -> stackoverflow.com -> echo '<''img src="img/stackoverflowcom.png">';
```

And i can't find right code or methods to separate url...

If there is a right way to do so, please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=php+url";
echo parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
```

You can also fetch all the parts of the url if you need them  as well.

```
print_r(parse_url($url));       // that will also give you host with other parts
```